# Can Anyone explain the significance of Q-mean value?

Tags: biostatistics, bioinformatics

I have been using the [Swiss Model](http://swissmodel.expasy.org/interactive/fJrTJq/models/) for modelling protein structures. It returns the modelling result with the estimation of nativeness of the structure through the Q-mean4 value. I have even read the [paper](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/27/3/343.long) but could not make out its significance. Can anyone explain it in layman's terms. What do positive and negative, high and low Q-mean4 values mean?